# why do mat-form-field components flicker/temporarily disappear when I hover over a chrome browser tab?

Tags: angular, google-chrome, flicker, mat-form-field

Experienced in the latest versions of Angular 15 and Angular 16
Chrome browser Version 118.0.5993.89 (Official Build) (64-bit)

When I have my angular application open and I hover over a chrome browser tab things seem to temporarily disappear

[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUpdM.png)

[on hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYTz3.png)

I also tried it on the angular material site

[same issue on angular material site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DjqZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I enabled hardware acceleration in Settings/System Settings/Use Hardware Acceleration and the problem went away.